# import Numpy and cv2 error in pycharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, pycharm

I am trying to set up theano in Pycharm community edition 4.5. I am working on ubuntu 12.04.
I have two questions,

```
1) import numpy gives error, although when i check project interpreter i see numpy installed.
2) import cv2; (this is underlined with red line).
```

The error on pycharm console is givn below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/pycharm-community-4.5/helpers /pydev/pydevd.py", line 2357, in <module> 
 globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
 File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/pycharm-community-4.5/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1777, in run
 pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
 File "/scr/Ihsan/22-april-code/my_convolutional_mlp_2.py", line 29, in <module>
 import numpy
 File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/pycharm-community-4.5/helpers/pydev/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
 return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 170, in <module>
  from . import add_newdocs
File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/pycharm-community-4.5/helpers/pydev/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
 return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/ihsan/Documents/pycharm-community-4.5/helpers/pydev/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
  return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 17, in <module> 
  from . import scimath as emath
ImportError: cannot import name scimath

Process finished with exit code 1
```

But my first problem is with numpy, it stops with import numpy and does not go further.
Any clue how to solve it?

Comment: you need to install `scipy` it looks like: `ImportError: cannot import name scimath`

Comment: I would suggest installing something like Python(x,y) or my personal favorite Anaconda.  These help you to manage installations correctly.

Comment: Do you have multiple python installations or any virtual environments?

Comment: @KronoS, if OP is using pycharm, OP may want to [install packages through pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) instead of complicating the problem with another installation.

Comment: @wflynny I'm not sure that pycharm always does a good enough job of installing dependencies with the packages.

Comment: @wflynny i can not download scimath through pycharm. it gives error.

Comment: I think moving to anaconda will make me suffer more, i will prefer to use pycharm. currently i am use too with it. So how should i install scimath

Comment: @khan Install scipy through pycharm, not scimath.

Comment: @wflynny it was already there, even i install scipy again but still give same error.

Comment: i solved that problem with the help of this post. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52703/using-atlas-from-scipy

Comment: But how to solve now the second part. No module name cv2

Comment: You need to install OpenCV, have a look at http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html.

Comment: @Greg Yes still gave the same error

Comment: I just noticed that that only install OpenCV and not the Python bindings which is probably why you still get the ImportError, maybe http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_fedora/py_setup_in_fedora.html#install-opencv-python-in-fedora can help you.

Answer (score -1):

I am unaware how much experience you have with Python, so sorry if my answer is too simple, but have you tried installing scimath by typing

```
pip install scimath
```

in a console/terminal?

Comment: Gives error : ImportError: libatlas.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory